# Multiple Tooltip Content Sources Defined via Array Object

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

I am using jQuery UI to have multiple tooltips on a page that fetch the content from different attributes.

There is an object being created that defines which will be the source for each tooltip, depending on it's class.

Something like:

```
var tooltipparam = [{"class":".one","source":"alt"}, {"class":".two","source":"title"},{"class":".three","source":"alt"}];
```

Then I'm doing a loop to create the tooltips, like this:

```
for (var key in tooltipparam) {

    var source = tooltipparam[key]['source'];
    $(tooltipparam[key]['class']).tooltip({
            content: function () { return $(this).attr(source) }
        });
}
```

However, the toolips are being created using the latest setting of the parameters object. In this case fetching the alt attribute ({"class":".three","source":"alt"} and creating all the tooltips like this.

What I am missing?

Here's a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cmoreira/vqRH5/

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your `var source` is a global variable. When the tooltip content function is called, that is to say when your mouse enter your `<a/>` element, the value of the `source` variable is the last one set so 'alt'.

I don't know your requirement, but if you want to retrieve the tooltip content from different attributes you can proceed like that :

**HTML**:

```
<div class="tooltip" title="tooltip from title" />
<img class="tooltip" alt="tooltip from alt" src="..."/>
```

**JS**:

```
$(".tooltip").tooltip({
    content: function () {
        var _this = jQuery(this);
        return _this.attr('title') != '' ? 
            _this.attr('title') : _this.attr('alt');
    }
});
```